# poderia me ajudar por favor . Como ordeno essa struct pelo metodo do insert short?

Tags: c++

Como  eu  faço para  ordenar as struct usando  o insert  short sou  novo  na  programação  se  puderem me ajudar  por  favor e explicar , vou enviar o  codigo  que  fiz :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


struct Familia {

    int IdadePai;
    int IdadeMae;
    int IdadeFilho;

};


void insertion_sort( Familia  lista [], int  tam ){

    int  valor_pivo;
    int aux ; 
    int j;
    int posPivo ;

    for (int i = 1; i < tam ; i++) {

     valor_pivo = lista [i].IdadePai;
     posPivo = i ;
     j = i - 1;

     while ((j >= 0) and (valor_pivo < lista [j].IdadePai)){

        aux = lista [j].IdadePai;
        lista [j] = lista[posPivo].IdadePai;
        lista[posPivo].IdadePai = aux ;

        aux = lista [j].IdadeMae;
        lista [j] = lista[posPivo].IdadeMae;
        lista[posPivo].IdadeMae = aux ;

        aux = lista [j].IdadeMae;
        lista [j].IdadeMae = lista[posPivo].IdadeMae;
        lista[posPivo].IdadeMae = aux ;

         j--;

     }

        aux = lista [j].IdadePai;
        lista [j] = lista[posPivo].IdadePai;
        lista[posPivo].IdadePai = aux ;

        aux = lista [j].IdadeMae;
        lista [j] = lista[posPivo].IdadeMae;
        lista[posPivo].IdadeMae = aux ;

        aux = lista [j].IdadeMae;
        lista [j].IdadeMae = lista[posPivo].IdadeMae;
        lista[posPivo].IdadeMae = aux ;


    }

}

int main(){

    Familia lista [5];
    bool igual = false ;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){

        cin  >> lista[i].IdadePai;
        cin  >> lista[i].IdadeMae;
        cin  >> lista[i].IdadeFilho;

    }

   insertion_sort( lista , 5);


    for (int j = 0 ; j < 5; j++){

        for (int k = j ; k < 5; k ++){

                if (lista[j].IdadeFilho == lista[k].IdadeFilho ){

                    cout << lista[j].IdadePai << "  " ;
                    cout <<  lista[j].IdadeMae << "  " ;

            igual = true ;

        }else {

            igual = false ; 

        }

        }

    }



    if( igual == false ){

        cout  << -1 ;


    } 


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Definido já pelo nome, insertion sort é um algoritmo que ordena um contêiner automaticamente durante a inserção. Ele é útil quando é necessário que a cada nova inserção o contêiner esteja ordenado, em situações em que existe um ganho de performance justificável como, por exemplo, uma lista em que pesquisas binárias são mais frequentes que inserções.

O seu código não faz muito sentido pq vc recebe a entrada do usuário, adiciona ao vetor sem ser pelo insertion sort e aí depois tenta ordenar o contêiner por fora. Isso não é eficiente, pq para usar o insertion sort nessa situação é necessário recopiar o vetor inteiro e ir inserindo os valores um a um no novo vetor ordenado. Um algoritmo como QuickSort seria uma escolha melhor.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Familia
{
    unsigned int IdadePai;
    unsigned int IdadeMae;
    unsigned int IdadeFilho;
};

void insertion_sort(Familia novo_item, Familia lista[], int tam)
{
    int posicao_item = -1;

    //encontrar posição de inserção
    for(int i=0; i<tam; i++) {
        if(novo_item.IdadePai < lista[i].IdadePai ) {
            posicao_item = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    //se novo item não for menor que nenhum dos itens na lista, não inserir
    if(posicao_item == -1)
        return;

    //de trás pra frente, empurre itens depois de posição para o final
    for(int i=(tam-1); i>posicao_item; i--) {
        lista[i] = lista[i-1];
    }

    //inserir item na posição
    lista[posicao_item] = novo_item;
}

#define INF 0xFFFFFFFF

int main()
{
    //entrada
    const Familia familia[5] = {{ 2, 2, 2 },
                                { 3, 3, 3 },
                                { 1, 1, 1 },
                                { 5, 5, 5 },
                                { 4, 4, 4 }};

    //lista vazia
    Familia familia_ordenada[5] = {{ INF, INF, INF },
                                   { INF, INF, INF },
                                   { INF, INF, INF },
                                   { INF, INF, INF },
                                   { INF, INF, INF }};

    //adicionando e ordenando itens com insertion sort
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << "\nPasse: " << i+1 << "\n";
        insertion_sort(familia[i], familia_ordenada, 5);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            cout << " { "   << familia_ordenada[i].IdadePai   << ", "
                            << familia_ordenada[i].IdadeMae   << ", "
                            << familia_ordenada[i].IdadeFilho << " }\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
Passe: 1
 { 2, 2, 2 }
 { 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295 }
 { 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295 }
 { 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295 }
 { 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295 }

Passe: 2
 { 2, 2, 2 }
 { 3, 3, 3 }
 { 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295 }
 { 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295 }
 { 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295 }

Passe: 3
 { 1, 1, 1 }
 { 2, 2, 2 }
 { 3, 3, 3 }
 { 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295 }
 { 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295 }

Passe: 4
 { 1, 1, 1 }
 { 2, 2, 2 }
 { 3, 3, 3 }
 { 5, 5, 5 }
 { 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295 }

Passe: 5
 { 1, 1, 1 }
 { 2, 2, 2 }
 { 3, 3, 3 }
 { 4, 4, 4 }
 { 5, 5, 5 }
```

Reescrevi seu código para deixar mais clara a implementação do insertion sort e para ter uma referência melhor de como se usar o algoritmo. Boa sorte nos seus estudos.